# INSERT private message system PDO php

Tags: php, pdo, message

I am trying to build a little private message system in PHP, i am using PDO as connection to the database. i have got the most to work excpet the most important part.

I cannot get the insert message to write anything to the database so i would love some help.

I will first post my database so you all can see what we are working with here.
starting with my users

```
id int(10) UN AI PK 
username varchar(30) 
password varchar(100) 
regdate datetime
```

This is my message table which im trying to write the message to

```
id int(11) AI PK 
from_user varchar(45) 
to_user varchar(45) 
subject varchar(400) 
message text 
date date 
read tinyint(4)
```

I have tried a couple of diffrent code to get it to work
i will now paste the code that according to my error check says that the message  was succesfully sent...

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO private_messages VALUES('',$user, 
$to_user','$subject',$message','$date','0')
";

    echo "Youre message was succesfully sent...";
```

But this does not work and i know that this is probably not the right way when using PDO.

I have also tried this

```
$query =$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO private_messages(user, to_user, subject, 
message,
date);
VALUES('',$user, $to_user','$subject',$message','$date','0')
");

$query->bindParam(":user", $user);
$query->bindParam(":to_user", $to_user);
$query->bindParam(":subject", $subject);
$query->bindParam(":message", $message);

if ($query->execute()) {
    $success = true;
}
```

but then i get Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

I will also post the form im using if that can be of any value

```
echo "
<form action='compose.inc.php' method='POST'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>To: </td>
<td><input type='text' name='to_user'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Subject: </td>
<td><input type='text' name='subject'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Message:</td>
<td><textarea name='message' rows='10' cols='50'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td colspan='2'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send Message'/>
</td>
</r>
</table>
</form>

  ";
```

When doing this message system ive been following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BED_yMC7qv0 , its using mysqli and i have been trying to decode it to PDO, i think the problem lies therein

So short recap
My error check says that my message are sent.
Nothing gets written to my database.
im trying to use PDO.

If a i cant find a solution i would love to get pointers to tutorial or books or anything that are about message system with PDO.
Best regards /Robert

Comment: You should [read the manual about prepared statements.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). When you bind variables, you need to add placeholders instead of concatenating the values in the query.

Comment: You also have an unmatched single quote: `, $to_user',`

Comment: I have removed that quote, didnt helpt i have also used $sql = "
 INSERT INTO private_messages (user, ) and 
 VALUES (:user,) $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);                              
       $stmt->bindValue(":user", $_POST["user"]); if ($stmt->execute()) {
  $success = true; 
 } <-- a short version but in this fashion with all values ofc

Comment: Like I suggested, read the manual about how to use prepared statements. You're mixing concatenation and prepared statements, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inserting the variables into the query you do this by binding them.

```
$query =$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO private_messages (user,to_user,subject,message,date)
VALUES(:user,:to_user,:subject,:message,NOW())");

$query->bindParam(":user", $user);
$query->bindParam(":to_user", $to_user);
$query->bindParam(":subject", $subject);
$query->bindParam(":message", $message);

if ($query->execute()) {
    $success = true;
}
```

Also you should match the amount of values to the amount of columns.

Comment: I have tried something simillar. But what happens is this   Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQLuse near '; VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1 in  37): PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO pri...') #1                                                                                                                        But im using pretty much the same to register a user, and that works fine.

Comment: what do you mean by 'this'?

Comment: Ah sorry I see the error now :-) you should remove the `;` after `date)` I will change this in my answer.

Comment: Something else must be wrong in my code casue all i get is Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in C:\MAMP\htdocs\c9_sandbox\msg\compose.inc.php:45 Stack trace: #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\c9_sandbox\msg\compose.inc.php(45): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\MAMP\htdocs\c9_sandbox\messages.php(52): include('C:\\MAMP\\htdocs\\...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\c9_sandbox\msg\compose.inc.php on line 45  The line in this particular error is  if ($query->execute()) {
    $success = true;
}

Comment: The error message is pretty self explaining, we give the query 5 parameters but further down we only bind 4. As you can see we are missing the `:date`. depending on your table structure you can either use the [php function date](php.net/date) to assign a value or replace it with [MySQL NOW() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

Comment: solved with your code and i used    :date)");
$query->bindParam(":from_user",$user);  It works to write to the db now :)

Comment: Glad to hear that.